# How to register keystrokes on a image tag?

Tags: jquery, keystroke

I am making a clicker game that has keystroke and click function. I was not able to add the keystroke function. I have been using jQuery to code my clicker game.

```js
var numClicks = 0;

$("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks);

$("img").on('click', function()

  {
    numClicks++;
    $("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
 
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" width="500" height="600">
```

I expected my code would receive my keyboard inputs as clicks without actually having to click. I've checked for several different pieces of code which could potentially work but with no luck. The results of my code are literally nothing. Nothing happens.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event "The click event fires when a pointing device button (e.g., a mouse's primary button) is pressed and released on a single element."

Comment: _"I expected my code would receive my keyboard inputs as clicks without actually having to click."_ Bad assumption. Look into keydown, keyup, and keypress

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code to increment variable by keyboard key press (or hold) using jQuery lib:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numClicks = 0;
  $("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks );

  $(document).on('keydown', function() {
    numClicks++;
    $("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In stead of listening to the `click` on image, you can register a listener for `keydown` on image. Also you need to add a `tabindex` to the `<img` or the `div` containing it.

```js
var numClicks = 0;

$("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks);

$("img").on('click', function() {
    numClicks++;
    $("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks);
  });



$('#myImage').bind('keydown', function(event) {
  //console.log(event.keyCode);
  numClicks++;
  $("#results").text("Money earned $" + numClicks);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="imageContainer" >
  <img id="myImage" tabindex="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" width="500" height="600"></div>
```